# UIButton in UIToolbar not responding after alpha change

Tags: ios, uibutton

I've got a project created using storyboards. I have a `UIToolbar`, in it a `UIToolarItem` and in that a `UIButton`.

When the user taps on the screen it triggers an action that will animate the alpha value of the `UIButton`

as below: (this is the method being called to change the alpha of the button

```
- (IBAction)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"tapped: %f", self.mainViewToolbar.alpha);
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);


    if (self.buttonCall.alpha > 0.0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(void) {
            self.buttonCall.alpha = 0.0;
        }];
    }
    else //(self.buttonEmergencyCall.alpha < 1.0)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay: 0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                         animations:^{
                             self.buttonCall.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion:nil];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay: 5.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                         animations:^{
                             self.buttonCall.alpha = 0.0;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }


    if (sender.view == self.toolbarForMainScreen) {
        NSLog(@"clicking on the toolbar");
    }

}
```

The button response to clicks *until* the code above is run, then it stops responding to user taps.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you even see the button after the animation?

Comment: no, the alpha is change to 0.0. However when touch the screen again it changes alpha to 1.0 (should've put that in the post, sorry)...after that I can see it but can't touch it.

Comment: hmm... it is better to give more code.

Comment: changing alpha from 1 to 0 and back to 1 should not affect the responsiveness of the button. you've overlooked something

Answer (score 1):

you are setting alpha is 0 that you controller going to be hide.you must set minimum alpha is 0.1 for getting it's event else button going to hide. See this i test with demo that i setting one `IBAction` with click touch up inside Method:

```
 float alf = 1.0;
- (IBAction)addSubview:(id)sender
{
    [self.btnAdd setAlpha:alf];

    alf-=0.1;
    NSLog(@"Tapp working");

}
```

and each click of Button i decrease 0.1 from alpha 1 and it method called till that button alpha is 0.1 then not calling. So it means that when you setting alpha is 0 that controller going to be hide. **At list you have to set minimum Alpha of control is 0.1**

[image]

Comment: actually every button is touchable while the alpha is not smaller than `0.01f` (1%).

Answer (score 0):

See, if any other view overlaps over the UIbutton, then

Comment: How would I figure that out? I'm not moving any views around the screen..just changing alpha on button from 1.0 - 0.0 - 1.0.

Comment: What if you remove the animation? Does the button respond then?

Comment: Maybe adding a sentence after then would make this a real answer. Until then, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Practice:** Try using completion block like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    self.buttonCall.alpha = 1.0;        

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        self.buttonCall.alpha = 0.0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    }];
}];
```

Comment: You don't need to mark your answers with **solution** every time. If it's the solution the person who asked the question will mark it as such.

Comment: @Calvedos, hmm your are right. I just want to have some sections in my answer lets say solution, explanation, best practice and so on. But its giving an ambiguity sorry for that.